# I have a question about question tags

Tags: negation, tag-questions

Which sentence has correct question tag, and why?

1. There's little chance for me to win the game, isn't there?
2. There's little chance for me to win the game, is there?

Comment: Neither 1, nor 2, *isn't it*.

Answer (score 3):

The correct version ends with "*is*".

This type of affirmation-seeking usually uses a form contrary to what was asked, for example:

- It **is**, **isn't** it?
- It **is not**, **is** it?
- There **is** a chance, **isn't** there?

However, although you're saying "there *is* little chance", this is a negative statement. The adjective 'little' in this context means 'negligible', or 'almost none'. It is essentially the same as saying "there **is not much** chance". So the confirmation takes a positive form:

> There's little chance for me to win the game, is there?